# A program that checks whether a number is between 10 and 50 in c++

Tags: c++, math

i have a task in c++. I have to write program checks whether a number is between 10 and 50. I wrote something but it errors, can you help me please.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    
    cout << "enter number";
    cin >> a;
    
    if ( 10 < a < 50)
        cout << "True";
    else
        cout << "False";


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure `10 < a < 50` isn't doing what you think it does. Might want to brush up on the logical and operator (`&&`).

Comment: Think about what `10 < a < 50` means. It is not the same as `10 < a && a < 50`, the two `<` operators are separate, not a part of some single construct for comparison.

Comment: "it errors" is not a good problem description. Better to describe more precisely what is going wrong.

Comment: Turn on warnings.  Fix warnings.  Better code.  (For example, `-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare` and `-Wunreachable-code`.)

Answer (score 3):

The expression `10 < a < 50` is actually the same as `(10 < a) < 50`.

So it compares the *boolean* true or false result of `10 < a` with the integer value `50`.

The comparison will *always* be true, since `10 < a` will be either `0` or `1` when converted from `false` or `true`, respectively.

You need to make two separate comparisons, chained together with the logic AND operator `&&`, like `10 < a && a < 50`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write if statements like `a < b < c`. You can compare only two things at the moment, so, you have to change your if statement like that

```
if (a > 10 && a < 50){
    // correct
} else {
    // not correct
}
```

In C++, `&&` is a logic AND, while `||` is a logic OR. Now, this statement means "if a is more than 10 AND a is fewer than 50.

### Update

Actually, you can compare `a < b < c`, but this will lead to behavior that you probably are not expecting. Instead of that, will be better to use logic AND and logic OR to separate such a comparements into several, much simple comparements like `a < b AND b < c`.

Comment: Actually you can write expressions like `a < b < c` and they are perfectly valid. Doesn't mean it's clear to the reader, will exhibit the desired behavior, or even a good idea but it's valid.